# Spark session application formatting in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I wrote few codes in scala and executed in spark-shell.

However, I want all the codes in a spark application. I tried to format it as much as possible. but I am still getting formatting errors. Can somebody debug it entirely?

kindly ignore the comments as they are the questions I need to solve

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql

object functions {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()


    val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema",  "true").csv("aadhaar_data.csv").toDF("date", "registrar", "private_agency",     "state", "district", "sub_district", "pincode", "gender", "age",    "aadhaar_generated", "rejected", "mobile_number", "email_id")

df.registerTempTable("data")


    //1. View/result of the top 25 rows from each individual store.

    spark.sql("select * from (select *,row_number() over (partition by private_agency   order by private_agency desc) as Row_Num from data) as b where  b.Row_Num<=25").show(30)


    //Checkpoint 2

    //1. Describe the schema

    df.printSchema()

    //2. Find the count and names of registrars in the table.

    df.select("registrar").distinct().show()
    df.select("registrar").distinct().count()

 //3. Find the number of states, districts in each state and sub-districts in each  district.

    df.select("state").distinct().count()
    spark.sql("SELECT state, COUNT(district) AS district_count FROM data GROUP BY   state ORDER BY COUNT(district) DESC").show()
    spark.sql("SELECT district, COUNT(sub_district) AS sub_district_count FROM data     GROUP BY district ORDER BY COUNT(sub_district) DESC").show()


//4. Find out the names of private agencies for each state.

    spark.sql("SELECT state, private_agency FROM data GROUP BY state,   private_agency ORDER BY state").show(2000, false)


//Checkpoint3

//1. Find top 3 states generating most number of Aadhaar cards?

    spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT state, SUM(aadhaar_generated) AS aadhaar_count FROM    data GROUP BY state ORDER BY aadhaar_count DESC LIMIT 3").show()




    //2. Find top 3 districts where enrolment numbers are maximum?

    val generated = df.groupBy("district").sum("aadhaar_generated")
    val rejected = df.groupBy("district").sum("rejected")
    val concat = generated.withColumn("id",     monotonically_increasing_id()).join(rejected.withColumn("id",   monotonically_increasing_id()), Seq("id")).drop("id")

    val final = concat.withColumn("Sum_Value", $"sum(aadhaar_generated)" +  $"sum(rejected)")
    println("top 3 districts where enrolment numbers are maximum along with the number  of enrolments")
    final.show(3, false)


//3. Find the no. of Aadhaar cards generated in each state?

    spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT state, SUM(aadhaar_generated) AS aadhaar_count FROM    data GROUP BY state").show()


//Checkpoint 4:
//1. Find the number of unique pincodes in the data?

    df.select("pincode").distinct.show()

    //2. Find the number of Aadhaar registrations rejected in Uttar Pradesh and
    Maharashtra ?

    spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT state, SUM(rejected) AS rejected_count FROM data   GROUP BY state having (state='Uttar Pradesh' OR state='Maharashtra')").show()
```

PS: I tried to make the application in intellij idea

Comment: Could you please list out the errors that you get while running the above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you are facing issue with groupBy and withColumn.

Find below syntax to do groupBy.

Syntax:

```
df1.groupBy("Grouping_Column").agg(sum(column_to_sum).alias(Some_new_column_name))
```

For withColumn, probably val concat must be throwing an issue. follow the syntax for defining withColumn. you will get it.

Comment: the requirement is to do using sparksession

Comment: For groupBy provided syntax, Please test and verify.